# Online - Master Degree In Sound Design (or) Audio Production

Tags: online, master, degree, sound-design

Hi Audio Pros,

I would like to know if there are any online college that offer a Masters degree in Sound Design (or) Audio Production.

The reason that im asking this is because i have no formal education in audio & i would like to work abroad, but looking at the VISA requirements i guess a degree is a must, But Im am a sound guy completely experience based & i have 6 years of experience in audio feild as a Sound Editor/Game Audio Artist.

Kindly advice me on this,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Some places will offer you a place without a degree if you're relevant industry experience is sufficient so don't be put off by that. I did a Masters in Sound Design at Bournemouth University, but I don't think that course is running anymore. I know there is one in Edinburgh that at least one SSD regular attends (G A Harry - I'm looking at you! ;) ). There are a few others in the UK too, including the NFTS. Be prepared to pay a LOT for one, and weigh up the pros and cons if you're that serious. Having a Master's doesn't necessarily assure you employment at the end of it. Far from it.

I can't speak for any others outside the UK but I'm sure others will chip in. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply andy lewis, 

1. Yes its true that a Master's degree doesn't necessarily assure employment, but for work visa a degree is very necessary i guess , please correct me if im wrong here.

2. Does US immigration consider audio engineer or sound editor to be a job that doesn't require a degree? if so this gives me a little hope as another SSD'ian commented. 

Answer (score 1):

You might want to talk to an immigration lawyer before starting any courses. Just from my visa experience in the US, it seems they don't deem audio engineer or sound editor to be a job that requires a degree, which weakens your position when applying for certain visas. If you can link your degree experience to things like directing voice talent, that can bolster your application, as directing IS something US immigration believes to require a degree.

But this is just for the US, and i'm not a lawyer so i can't guarantee how accurate my info is; this is just what i remember from my application a year ago. Talk to a good immigration lawyer, they'll be able to make things clear for you.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Roger Middenway, Your comment gives me a little hope & sure i'll check this issue with an immigration lawyer.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Edinburgh Napier has an online Sound Design Master's: http://www.courses.napier.ac.uk/SoundDesign_W56742.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's a sound design MA in Edinburgh. Here in Barcelona you have 2 other options at the Pompeu I Fabra University, the Sound Computing MA and a posgraduate in Sonology. Another option would be to study the Audio Production Degree at any SAE in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the Sound Design degree is no longer offered at Bournemouth, but we do have an MA in Sound Production for Film and Television or an MSc in Digital Music and Audio Production.  Both of these have taught elements by the members of the old SD team.  I teach on MSc if you want anymore details.

Comment: Hi there. Just wondering who is left there doing the teaching from the old SD team? Gary and Maike?


Comment: Gary and Maike are both still there.  Maike actually teaches Aesthetics on the MSc that I teach on.  Stephen has retired, but does still pop in to guest stuff. 

Comment: Cool. Tell them I said Hi!Im stil down in Bournemouth after moving down to be with girlfriend after Uni. If you ever need any help with anything let me know. More than happy to help if I can :)

Comment: Will say Hi for you.  I'll also drop you an email so we can talk.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have 6 years experience in related fields then I'd say a decent showreel is worth more than a Masters Degree by a long shot...!